# Need help understand a sentence

Tags: vocabulary, sentence

This is taken from a book called "A Brief History of the Future: The origins of the internet", page 10, by John Naughton

> Later, driving home in the dark, I asked, "Da, is Mr Clarke very rich?" He replied laconically "Well, he doesn't want for a bob or two anyway," and I finally understood why my father had never obtained his license.

What does `he doesn't want for a bob or two anyway` mean?

Comment: ..this should be easy to figure out by discovering what all the words could mean.

Comment: "Bob" was a colloquial term for the British  pre-decimal coin the shilling. The father meant "He's not short of cash."

Comment: @Kate Bunting, thank you. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll mark it as such. Also, why is the grammar so strange? I was thrown off by the `want for` part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Bob" was a colloquial term for the British pre-decimal coin the shilling.  The father meant "He's not short of cash." ("Want" is used in its old sense of "lack"; it doesn't mean "wish for".)

> **want** *verb*
>   3 (literary, no object) Lack something desirable or essential.
>   ‘you shall want for nothing while you are with me’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/want)